# Modular application structure for the MEAN app with Angular2 and material design

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, angular-material

I have to develop an application using MEAN Technology in which i have to use:

Angular 2 For client ui

Angular material css

Mongoose for ORM for mongodb

Typescript for writing server-side and client-side code

gulp task runner.

How do i structure my application so that it will be modular and easily   manageable and maintainable in Dev and production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I created an application recently that uses angular1, but with MEAN and mongoose and everything else you describe here... https://github.com/tydanielson/ctas-done-better If you want to create the angular2 part I recommend using the angular cli that gets everything in place https://cli.angular.io/  Lastly material for angular2 is in alpha and doesn't have nearly all the features with material and angular1 so be careful with expectations.